# Generate Vaadin forms from Activiti

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, activiti

1. Can I generate Vaadin forms (or simply Java beans or even html) directly from a process definition (a .bpmn20.xml or .bpmn file created using the Activiti designer plugin in Eclipse or the Activiti designer and where form properties were precised ) without coding it myself (using the Activiti source code for example)? -> by exploiting `extensionElements, activiti:formProperty, activiti:value`... tags.
2. And if so, is it possible to have forms changing automatically when the process definition (form properties) change?
3. Can I use the Activiti Explorer as a base of a production application and changing the code of the Activiti Explorer so that it meets my needs
   (When I import the activiti-explorer war file in Eclipse I don't find any java file to modify) (http://forums.activiti.org/content/extending-explorer) ?

Comment: I ask these questions because Aciviti Explorer (which is based on Vaadin) can do 1+2. The problem is that I'm not sure 3 is possible. In our team, we want to develop a process-based Human Resources web application.

Comment: I know that but I wasn't able to find inside it the code that does 1

Comment: You might want to check out the activiti-fork camunda which has embedded form support based on bpmn/variables. https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/usertask/task-form-embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Joram Barrez which is an Activiti Core Developer : 
"1 and 2. No, currently we don't have that feature 
 3. Sure- that is what open source is all about. You need to clone the source code from (http://www.github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/master/modules) and import it in Eclipse."

Answer posted in : (http://www.forums.activiti.org/content/generate-vaadin-forms)